# Getting class objects data from LinkedQueue

Tags: java, queue

First of all I wanted to say that this is my first post here so if I did anything wrong please let me know.

I have a class called EmployeeRecord:

```
void setEmployeeRecord(int empNo, String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.setEmpNo(empNo);
        this.setFirstName(firstName);
        this.setLastName(lastName);
        this.setAge(age);
    }
```

I also have Node class with basic `set/get Node next / Object element`, a LinkedQueue Class with `isEmpty(), insert, remove, getTail, size and search`.

In my GUI I have 4 textfields with employeeID, firstName, lastName and age.

When I press insert I want to add these values into a

`EmployeeRecord er = new EmployeeRecord();` -> `er.setEmployeeRecord(num, fN, lN, agei);`

and then I want to add them to my LinkedQueue - `lq.append(er);`

The problem I have is when I want to display the information stored in my LinkedQueue into a TextArea.
I can't find a way to get 'actual' data from it, currently I have something like this :

```
 textArea.setText(lq.Search()); 

 -> 

 //This is the LinkedQueue class
 public String Search() {
    String msg = "";
    Node currentNode = this.head;
    while (currentNode != null) {
        msg += (currentNode.getElement().toString() + "\n");
        currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
    }

    return msg;
}
```

the output I get is : `appletviewer.EmployeeRecord@2e1a6955`

How can I get the actual output that I would easly get with the ArrayList?

(I can't use ArrayList!)

Comment: Queues in Java are used primarily in the concurrent package.  Is that what you want?  Which queue in particular are you using, `LinkedBlockingQueue` perhaps?

Comment: Write a formatter which takes an instance of `EmployeeRecord` and returns `String` in a predefined formatted way - avoid `toString` for presentation, as it limits the available options and `toString` should be generally used for debugging purposes

Comment: @markspace `LinkedQueue lq = new LinkedQueue();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the **`toString()`** method in `EmployeeRecord`.

You saved an EmployeeRecord object in the queue. When printing the element, the toString() function of the object is called. If you don't override it, the default one is used and prints the identifier of the object.

Try something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return "EmpNo: " +  empNo  + "\nFirstName: "+ firstName + "\nLastName: " + lastName + "\nAge: "+age;
}
```

Comment: There are several types of queues that do override the `toString()` method.  So I'm wondering which class the OP is using which doesn't.

Comment: Yeahh, the queues override the toString() method for basic data types (like Integer or String). But if you put an self-defined object like EmployeeRecord in it, you have to implement the toString() by yourself.

Comment: @rheinz but doesnt this display just the current/newest one? Any way I could do a for each to display all the objects? (for example if I had 5 employeeRecords added?)

Comment: I get your point. But I think it's possible to iterate through the queue elements in the LinkedQueue class and call for every element currentNode.toString();

Comment: Have you tried just adding the toString() in EmployeeRecord? In my opinion your search() method looks good. To your question: you iterate through every element because of the while-loop in your queue. And you call for every element the toString(). That is right. But the toString() in your self defined EmployeeRecord class doesnt no what to return, so it just returns the identifier. If you override the toString() you can control the return.

Answer (score 0):

"currentNode.getElement().toString()" is converting information **of current node** into string, not the actual information **inside current node** and in this case both of them are not same because current node is a type of Node object.
To show information of an employee you have to further ask for particulars from current node and in this case both informations will be matched, as currentNode.particular is an Element object.

So modification in your code should be

```
msg += (currentNode.name+" "+currentNode.empnum+ "\n");
```

where `name` and `empnum` should be replaced with the attributes of employee class.

Comment: If I would add this to my LinkedQueue class I would have to create `EmployeeRecord er = new EmployeeRecord()` inside the class which would make this values 0 or null all the times.

Comment: before adding to LinkedQueue you should call  _setEmployeeRecord_  method for every new object of Employee class.